# Set Cookies for URL Request

Tags: url, cookies, swift3, alamofire, urlrequest

Currently I have an iOS app that pulls prices and data from websites. So far its been working well, but I want to make it more accurate. To do so, I need to set the cookies for the URL request that I'm currently using String(contentsOf: _) for.

### Current Process

```
let requestUrl: URL = URL(string: "http://www.samsclub.com/sams/search/searchResults.jsp?searchTerm=Apple")!

var content: String?

do {
    content = try String(contentsOf: requestUrl)
} catch {
    print("Error while converting an NSURL to String: \(error)")
}

if content != "" {
    // I do things with the content of the requestUrl...
}
```

### Could Use?

I thought that maybe I should use Alamofire instead to pull those website, and then parse the data.

I need to set the cookie that changes the store number to search, but have been unable to find a way to do so. Bellow is the code I have for pulling the websites data **without** setting a cookie.

```
let requestUrl: String = "http://www.samsclub.com/sams/search/searchResults.jsp?searchTerm=Apple"

Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post).responseString { response in
    if let content: String = response.result.value {
        // I do things with the content of the requestUrl...
    }
}
```

### Other Claims

I have found many different ways to set cookies through Alamofire that don't work, but if Alamofire isn't the way to do it, please inform me. I really need this to work, and I'm open to any and every suggestion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It took four weeks to the day, but I figured it out! `URLRequest` and Alamofire were my glorious answers!

1. Create the URL to call.

   ```
   let requestUrl: String = "http://www.samsclub.com/sams/search/searchResults.jsp?searchTerm=Apple"
   ```
2. Next make the `URLRequest` with the URL string, and set its http method.

   ```
   var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
   urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
   ```
3. Then set the cookies for the `URLRequest`.

   ```
   urlRequest.setValue("myPreferredClub=4969", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
   urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
   ```
4. Finally send the `URLRequest` with Alamofire, and use the response data in whatever way I wish.

   ```
   Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseString { response in
       if let content: String = response.result.value {
           // I do things with the content of the urlRequest...
       }
   }
   ```